# Filename of selected file is invisible in Nemo file manager when focus is on other pane

Tags: filemanager, nemo

Open Nemo file manager. Enable View > Extra Pane option. Select one or more files in one pane. Click on the other pane. The filename(s) of the file(s) in the previous pane are not visible over the blue selection colour. How do I fix this?

DE: Gnome 3.36.4

Distro: Ubuntu

Nemo Version: 4.4.2

Theme: Adwaita but problem persists on switching to different themes

Screenshots:

[image: Focus is on one pane]

[image: Focus is on other pane]

Comment: Did you tried to switch theme using GNOME Tweaks?

Comment: @N0rbert this looks scaringly similar to the default Adwaita theme, the "reference GTK" theme. Unexpected that such issue would happen against Adwaita. Indeed, it is very important that the actual theme is identified.

Comment: @N0rber Yes, it was the Adwaita theme. The issue persists on switching themes.

Comment: @vanadium Yes, it was the Adwaita theme. The issue persists on switching themes.

Comment: Then you will have to look to the developpers of `nemo`. Probably it will work well with the themes of Linux Mint. Nemo is developped in the context of the Cinnamon desktop, initially on Linux Mint. Please add this information to your question (use "edit").